# ADFS Passing all claims to attribute store

Tags: attributes, store, adfs, claims-based-identity, claims

Is there a way to pass all claims of a user after log-in to an ADFS attribute store?

If there's a way, what claim rule should I add to the relying party?

Answer (score 1):

> c:[ ]
>   => issue(claim = c)

This would be a custom claim.

Comment: Yes, I've included that in my custom claims. How about if I need to pass it in an attribute store, what custom claim do I need to add? Thank you.